# Listing available METRO web services

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

**ENVIRONMENT** NetBeans 6.9.1, GlassFish 3.1 + METRO 2.1

I am hosting METRO web services, and I want to make a main page for the project that lists all of the hosted web services dynamically. Is there a way to implement this? What is needed to do it the practical way (JSF, ?)? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metro has excellent JMX support, if you enabling JMX monitoring as described in Chapter 19 of [Metro Guide](http://metro.java.net/guide/index.html), then you can use the JMX to dynamically query the deployed Web Services as described [here](http://metro.java.net/guide/Available_Monitoring_Information.html) using the WSEndpoint MBean.

Comment: @Bhaskar Karambelkar Thanks for the awesome pointer! Is it possible to use the WSEndpoint MBean on a facelets page, just like one would use a JSF MBean?

Comment: I haven't really worked with JSF, but if JSF can access JMX MBeans, then your job is very easy, if not, you may need to wrap the invokation of JMX MBean methods in a proxy bean, and have JSF invoke the proxy bean, just like JSF would access any normal BEAN.

Comment: If you're using SPRING, you can wrap the invocation on the WSEndpoint MBean inside MBeanProxyFactoryBean. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jmx.html Sec 20.6

Comment: @Bhaskar Karambelkar Thanks again! I'm going with the JSF direction, I  don't want to include Spring until it's absolutely necessary. I'm currently listing MBeans via `mBeanServer.queryNames(ObjectName.WILDCARD, ObjectName.WILDCARD);` but I don't see WSEndpoint in the list. However I see this at deploy: `INFO: Metro monitoring rootname successfully set to: amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=WSEndpoint,name=/JavaWSJMX-WSnameWSService-WSnameWSPort`. How can I get a reference?

Comment: Daniel, I really wouldn't know how to get a reference in JSF, btw, did you try connecting to your JVM , via JConsole, and see if you can find WSEndpoint via JConsole, if you can , then there's no reason JSF can't find it.

Comment: @Bhaskar Karambelkar I've got a strange phenomenon (probably I'm just too new to these things): After WS deploy I see only around 62 MBeans, and I don't see the WSEndpoint. If I run JMXterm the number of MBeans jumps up to 401, and WSEndpoint is visible. If I use JConsole, again I can't see the WSEndpoint. However, if I was using JMXterm before, then WSEndpoint is visible from JConsole too.